# Insert a space after the second character followed by every three characters

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to insert a space after two characters, followed by a space after every three characters.

**Data:**

```
97100101101102101
```

**Expected Output:**

```
97 100 101 101 102 101
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
sed 's/.\{2\}/& /3g'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In two steps:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/^.{2}/& /' -e 's/[^ ]{3}/& /g' <<< 97100101101102101
97 100 101 101 102 101
```

That is:

- `'s/^.{2}/& /'`
  catch the first two chars in the line and print them back with a space after.
- `'s/[^ ]{3}/& /g'`
  catch three consecutive non-space characters and print them back followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
$ echo '97100101101102101' | awk '{print substr($0,1,2) gensub(/.{3}/," &","g",substr($0,3))}'
97 100 101 101 102 101
```

Note that unlike the currently accepted sed solution this will not add a blank char to the end of the line, e.g. using `_` instead of a blank to make the issue visible:

```
$ echo '97100101101102101' | sed -r -e 's/^.{2}/&_/' -e 's/[^_]{3}/&_/g'
97_100_101_101_102_101_

$ echo '97100101101102101' | awk '{print substr($0,1,2) gensub(/.{3}/,"_&","g",substr($0,3))}'
97_100_101_101_102_101
```

and it would work even if the input contained blank chars:

```
$ echo '971 0101101102101' | sed -r -e 's/^.{2}/& /' -e 's/[^ ]{3}/& /g'
97 1 010 110 110 210 1

$ echo '971 0101101102101' | awk '{print substr($0,1,2) gensub(/.{3}/," &","g",substr($0,3))}'
97 1 0 101 101 102 101
```